# SharePoint 2013 Upload Attachment to list item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, custom-list

This may be a silly question.
But I am trying to upload a file to a specific list item in SharePoint list or library.
When I try uploading a pdf file the following happens...
[image]

[image]

Add then it does not load the file. Is there a setting on SharePoint or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Okay seems like its a browser issue with google chrome. I used IE11 and it worked first time.